# how to generate a random binary matrix with a specific condition in matlab?

Tags: matlab, function, matrix, random

If matrix A shows the number of group of ones in G (n,m) matrix like that

```
G = [ 1 1 0 0 1 
      0 1 1 1 0
      1 0 1 1 1 ]
```

so the A matrix will be

```
A = [ 2 1
      3 0
      1 3 ]
```

Then i want to generate (n,m) random matrix which the ones in this Matrix depend on A in the same order they appear

one solution will be

```
x = [ 0 1 1 0 1
      0 0 1 1 1
      1 0 1 1 1 ]
```

another solution

```
x = [ 1 1 0 1 0
      1 1 1 0 0
      1 0 1 1 1 ]
```

Comment: Why does this have an R tag?

Comment: What are the inputs? Whar is the desired output? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @lmo Maybe for the same reason it has `matlab` tag - R, Matlab and Octave are commonly used to handle matrices.

Comment: I fail to see how you get from `A` to `G` or vice versa (and also their relation to `x`). Could you please provide a **_detailed_ step by step** algorithm for generating the output from the input? Edit: nevermind, I see now that A counts **consecutive** ones in the rows of `G`.

Comment: @Crowley Does that mean we should include [tag:julia-lang], [tag:eigen], and [tag:wolfram-mathematica] just to be safe? No, tags are not used to try to get visibility, they are used to identify what this particular question is about. Someone searching for how to generate a random binary matrix in R will not want to see a question specifically about MATLAB with answers specifically made for MATLAB.

Comment: OP, what do you want? This is not a coding service. If there is something about Matlab that you don't understand or know, SO could help you. But no matter how fun it would be to develop an algorithm for this problem, it's not the intended purpose of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have a general solution that can also handle some (all?) edge cases like `G` with zero rows etc. The code below generates one instance of the `x` matrix.

Creating an `n`-by-`m` array of these `x`s  is left "as an exercise to the reader" (mainly because it's undefined whether OP wants it as a cell array of matrices or a 4-D logical/double array).

To understand what it does, see comments in the code + variable names. I hope it is clear enough (and that I didn't miss any edge cases).

```
function x = q37055681(G)
  %% Input
  if nargin < 1
    G = [ 1 1 0 0 1
          0 1 1 1 0
          1 0 1 1 1 ];
  end
  %% Input analysis:
  [A_ROWS,OUT_COLS] = size(G);
  transitions = find(diff(padarray(G.',1,false,'both').',1,2).');
  tr_per_ln = hist(ceil(transitions/(size(G,2)+1)),size(G,1))/2;
  A_COLS = max(tr_per_ln);
  missing_trans_per_line = A_COLS - tr_per_ln;
  groups_of_ones = diff(reshape(transitions,2,[]),1,1); % < result of RLE which ignores 0's
  % Count "fixing" based on the external definition of what to do with only 1 group per 
  % line (in this case, count it in the first element of A): 
  insrt = @(what, into, where) cat(2, into(1:where-1), what, into(where:end));
  for indZ = 1:sum(missing_trans_per_line(:))
    next_incomplete = find(missing_trans_per_line,1);
    groups_of_ones = insrt(0, groups_of_ones, A_COLS*next_incomplete-...
                                (missing_trans_per_line(next_incomplete)-1));
    missing_trans_per_line(next_incomplete) = missing_trans_per_line(next_incomplete)-1;
  end
  A = reshape(groups_of_ones,A_COLS,[]).';
  %% Generation of output:
  x = zeros(size(G));
  for indR = 1:A_ROWS
    tokens = cell(sum(A(indR,:)~=0),1);
    switch numel(tokens)
      case 0
        % we don't need to do anything, the entire line is 0.
        continue;
      case 1
        tokens{1} = repelem(true,A(indR,1));
      otherwise
        for indT = 1:numel(tokens)-1
          tokens{indT} = [repelem(true,A(indR,indT)) 0];
        end
        tokens{end} = repelem(true,A(indR,find(A(indR,:),1,'last')));
    end
    zero_tokens = repmat({0},[OUT_COLS-sum(A(indR,:))-(numel(tokens)-1),1]);  
    % Now we need to build a vector that selects randomly but SEQUENTIALLY from 
    % EITHER tokens or zero_tokens. 
    cell_to_pick_from = [ones(1,numel(tokens)) zeros(1,numel(zero_tokens))];
    choosing_order = cell_to_pick_from(randperm(numel(cell_to_pick_from)));
    % ^ Here's where the randomness comes in:
    x_line = [];
    for indC = 1:numel(choosing_order)
      if choosing_order(indC)
        % if it's 1, choose from "tokens"
        token = tokens{sum(choosing_order(1:indC)==1)};
      else
        % if it's 0, choose from "zeros"
        token = zero_tokens{sum(choosing_order(1:indC)==0)};
      end
      x_line = [x_line token]; %#ok
    end
    x(indR,:) = x_line;
  end
end
```