# i want a function to calculate the complete matrix for binary matrix?

Tags: matlab, function, matrix

if i have (rows,columns) matrix M like this

```
   M = [ 1 1 0 1 0 1
         0 1 1 0 1 0
         1 0 1 0 1 0
         0 1 0 1 0 1 
         1 1 0 1 1 1 ]
```

then i found this two Matrix M_row and M_col

```
  M_row = [ 2 1 1 
            2 1 0
            1 1 1
            1 1 1
            2 3 0 ]
```

which M_row shows how many of ones on every group of ones in each row in M

after that i fund sum_row and count_row like that which

sum_row shows the sum of element in M_row

```
  sum_row = [ 4
              3
              3
              3
              5 ]
```

count_row shows number of non zeros element in M_row

```
  count_row = [ 3
                2
                3
                3
                2 ]
```

for example last row in M_row is [1 3 0] which shows there is [1 0 0 1 1 1]

i want a function to

- first generate a (rows,columns) zeros matrix X
- second

  ```
   for k=1:n 
      if sum_row(k) +  count_row(k) - 1 == columns then 
  go back to M_row and convert this row element to group ones
  ```

for example k=1 , 4+3-1 = 6 which make the condition true then go bake to M_row and convert [ 2 1 1] to [ 1 1 0 1 0 1]

the final answer will be

```
      X = [ 1 1 0 1 0 1
            0 0 0 0 0 0
            0 0 0 0 0 0
            0 0 0 0 0 0
            1 1 0 1 1 1 ]
```

Comment: Is `M` an input? So are you just trying to filter `M`? Or do you only know `M_row`? It is not possible to reconstruct `M` from `M_row` as you can see from rows 3 and 4

Comment: M_row and sum_row and count_row i can found then , i want just to find X from M_row without using M

Comment: And what is `columns`? Is it always `6`?

Comment: No its a variable when the size of M change the rows and columns will change

Comment: You have already shown that the inputs you have are not sufficient to regenerate the matrix: row 3 and 4 of your initial M matrix are different but have the same representation in M_row, sum_row and count_row. How do you propose to overcome this?

Comment: It is not important how they are look in the M matrix , the important thing is to check the condition and if it is true then return to M_row and change them to group of ones

Comment: @user6296647 you keep asking questions about that topic, but when I wrote a comment in the other question, no reply from you came up. You only want us to give you a final solution without yourself invseting any efforts, right? :(

Comment: Am I the only one who don't understand the question? I feel a bit thick to be honest.

Comment: No Mr @tim , i already find the M_row and sum_row and count_row , i just want to generate a matrix X with like the example above

Comment: @user6296647 and what effort in the task of generating the matrix `X` have you invested? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Ok I gave you one simple solution using `for` -> Please implement the vectorized solution on your own.

Comment: "i want a function to..." Not only is there no effort shown to solve your own problem, there is no actual question in the entire post. This is nothing more than a "gimme teh codez" demand.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'll give a quick shot:

```
X = zeros(size(M));
numCols = size(M, 2);
for k=1:length(count_row)
    if sum_row(k)+count_row(k)-1 == numCols
       X(k,:) = M(k,:);
    end
end
```

IMO, no need to convert back from M to X, just take the whole row of M into X if the condition is met.

I left out vectorized code (which is nicer, shorter and faster) for your understanding (i.e. for-loop is easier to understand). If you want to speed it up, think about implementing vectorized indexing yourself instead of using a for-loop.

---

From what I read from the comment is: You don't have `M`, you only have `M_row`. Ok, then please first use the solution from your other question: [how to generate a random binary matrix with a specific condition in matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37055681/how-to-generate-a-random-binary-matrix-with-a-specific-condition-in-matlab) to generate `M_restored` from `M_row` and then use my code to generate `X` from `M_restored`.

Comment: I can found it by the approach but i want to use the M_row without M

Comment: So you mean, for whatever reason, you know `M_row` and `M_col`, but you don't know `M` itself -> Thus you want to generate X from `M_row` and not from `M`?

Comment: If so, why don't you use this algorithm to generate X from M_row? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37055681/how-to-generate-a-random-binary-matrix-with-a-specific-condition-in-matlab Slightly adapted it should work... Please make some efforts.

Comment: @user6296647: Do you ever vote anything or give credit to answers/comments? If not, it won't take long until no one helps anymore.